# how to select some columns with certain regularity

Tags: r

My data frame has 1440 columns as follows:

y180 y181 y182 y183 y184 y185 y186 y187 y188 y189 y190 y191 ...

I want to create a new data frame that keeps y180, y185, y190, y195, and so on. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select every 5th column of your data frame `dat`, use this command:

```
dat[ , c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 4))]
```

The following command also works if your columns are not ordered by their names. It selects rows whose numbers are divisible by 5:

```
dat[ , !as.numeric(sub("y", "", names(dat)) %% 5]
```